# How can I use regex to match a pattern in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a way to match parts of a string using regex.  So, I am trying to loop through files in a folder, which look like this:

```
mydata/2000/01/31/B/cor_pd_asia_bb.out.20000131.txt
mydata/2000/01/31/B/cor_pd_asia_sp_bb.out.20000131.txt
mydata/2000/01/31/B/cor_pd_euro_bb.out.20000131.txt
```

So, I am trying to match to this logic:

```
mydata/2000/01/31/B/cor_pd_[any_string].out.20000131.txt
```

How can I match to the string between the square brackets?  I tried to use the resource below, but nothing that I tried actually worked.

https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

If the match worked, the string that I tried would turn green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be:

```
(?:[^\/]+\/)*?cor_pd_([^_.]+(?:_[^_.]+)*)\.out\.\d{8}\.txt
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

```
(?:[^\/]+\/)*?    match path portion
cor_pd_           match literal 'cor_pd_'
(                 start capturing
    [^_.]+         then match a single path component    
    (?:_[^_.]+)*  followed by one or more separators and path components
)                 stop capturing
\.out\.\d{8}\.txt match literal '.out.20180101.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Something is off here, because it's still not working for me.  I know the problem is on my end.  I have to research this issue a bit more.  I'm close now.  Thanks for helping me to get this far!

Comment: If you can edit my demo and show where the problem is, I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: I just modified my original post.  I didn't want to give the exact strings that I am working with, but instead, just describe the concept.  I knew a guy who was 'laid off' for posting 'confidential information' on SO.  It was literally a question about consolidating multiple date formats into one single and date format.  So, it was a retarded and moronic excuse to start laying off people.  I'm still a bit hesitant to post actual information, and prefer to describe a concept, rather than an actual example.  Also, generic concepts probably help others, more than describing specific issues.